# Time Date Time Based Slots

Tags: mysql

**Logic**

1. Select time
2. Date

Corresponding to this date, time slots will show.

**e.g.**

```
<br/>
Time<br/>
11PM-2PM    3PM-6PM
<br/>
Date<br/>
12Aug 17Aug
<br/>
Time<br/>
11:30PM  1:30PM
```

I have a database table "timeslot"

```
max students for timeslot 20
1= All slots booked
0= slots are vacant

batch_datetime       class_strength is_booked
2021-07-16 16:30:00    20               1
2021-07-16 10:00:00    15               0
2021-07-15 12:30:00    10               1
```

The issue I have to show date booked when all slots of this date is booked.

Desire Result when All slots booked of that date

```
max students for timeslot 20
1= All slots booked
0= slots are vacant

batch_datetime       class_strength is_booked
2021-07-16              20               1
2021-07-15              10               1
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is often a good idea to post a db fiddle demo link with every mysql question.

Answer (score 0):

If im correct you need something like :

```
SELECT *  FROM mytable WHERE TIMEDIFF(time1,time2)  IN ( SELECT created_at FROM mytable WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01' AND is_book = 1)
```

In here you select everything from the table where the time is between a start and end time, inside that you check the start and end date given and the is_book equals to 1

Comment: Please never post "use this code" (code-only) answers on Stack Overflow.  Every answer should include an educational explanation with the intent to inform/inspire the OP and thousands of future researchers.  You are never only speaking to one person.  You are speaking to the OP, future readers of this page, and future readers of pages where this page was used to close a new page.  Please also use consistent uppercase characters when writing mysql keywords.  Using multiple lines for each clause can improve readability.